# Solid Lines with Different colors using Gnuplot in Perl

Tags: perl, gnuplot

I am trying to create a chart with two conditions :-

```
1) Solid lines 
2) Different colors .
```

Here is my code snippet :-

```
my $set = Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new(
        xdata => "words",
        ydata => "bits",
        title => "wordsvsbits",
        type => "matrix",
        font => "arial, 20",
        width => 7,
        style => "linespoints",
        linetype => "solid",
        imagesize  => "1.5,1.5",
        );
```

When i do this , I get solid lines with only one colour . If I dont give linetype , 
1st line is a solid (Red color), 2nd line is dashed with different color and 3rd line is also dashed with a new color .
Here I want to get new color for each line , but they should all  be solid lines .
Kindly , please help me .

Answer (score 0):

Until version 4.6. this is controlled by `set termoption solid`. In Perl this should work with

```
my $chart = Chart::Gnuplot->new(
    termoption => "solid",
);
```

and without specifying the `linetype`.

Comment: I tried is but I still get the same thing . 1 solid and 2 others dashed :(

Comment: Could you then please provide a full, runnable but minimal example?

Comment: my $set = Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new(
        xdata => $xdata,
        ydata => $ydata,
        title => $key,
        type => "matrix",
        font => "arial, 20",
        width => 7,
        style => "linespoint",
        imagesize  => "1.5,1.5",termoption => "solid",
        );

Comment: Thats not a full and runnable example. Note, you mustn't give the `termoption` to the `Chart::Gnuplot::Dataset->new`, but to `Chart::Gnuplot->new`.

Comment: $chart1 = Chart::Gnuplot->new(
      output => $title.".png" ,
      termoption => "solid",
      title  => {
      text => $xaxis."vs".$yaxis,
      font => "arial,25",
      },
      xlabel => $xaxis,
      ylabel => $yaxis,
      x2range => "xxx"
      xtics   => {
      mirror => 'off',
      },
      ytics   => {
      mirror => 'off',
      },
      x2tics  => 'on',
      y2tics  => 'on',
      grid => {
      type  => "dash",
      width => 0,
      }
  );

Comment: It says # This option cannot be changed using 'set termoption'

Comment: Which gnuplot version do you have? With 4.6.5 you can use `set termoption solid`. Otherwise you must give the `solid` option to the terminal settings `Chart::Gnuplot->(terminal => 'pngcairo enhanced solid', ...`. Note, that this will probably also change some other parts, because usually the module uses the postscript terminal and converts the output to png (in your case) using imagemagick. When you set the terminal explicitely, the conversion isn't done.